# What's wrong with this sequential video frame noise reduction function?

Tags: javascript

The idea is to reduce compression noise in video by leveraging sequential information. It's meant to record the past few frames of the video, observe the difference between each pixel and its recent predecessors, and if the pixel is similar, average its color with the previous pixels at that location.

The problem is that during the averaging step, as you'll see commented in the code below and the logs I'll post below that, the value that's supposed to add the color channel values of the recent frames and then divide by the count is instead not adding up, and being halved when I divide by the count (2, currently)

What mistake did I make and how can I fix this?

---

This example currently won't run properly as a StackOverflow example because it involves `getImageData` which triggers a CORS error and I don't know of a video source that would serve video with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Video/Canvas Demo 1</title>
<style>
  body {
    background: gray;
  }

  #c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  #c2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #v {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
</style>
<canvas id=c2></canvas>
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<video id=v controls loop autoplay>
  <source src=video.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
<script>
  let lastFrames = [];
  const edit = (c, cw, ch, c2) => {
    let portion = 0.7;
    cw = Math.round(cw * portion);
    ch = Math.round(ch * portion);
    let imageData = c.getImageData(0, 0, cw, ch);
    lastFrames.unshift(imageData);
    lastFrames = lastFrames.slice(0, 2);
    let current = imageData.data;
    let bufferData = [];
    lastFrames.forEach(frame => {
      let data = frame.data;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        let log = false;
        if (bufferData[i + 0] == undefined) bufferData[i + 0] = 0;
        if (bufferData[i + 1] == undefined) bufferData[i + 1] = 0;
        if (bufferData[i + 2] == undefined) bufferData[i + 2] = 0;
        else {
          log = true;
        }

        let rR = bufferData[i + 0] + data[i + 0]; // red
        let gR = bufferData[i + 1] + data[i + 1]; // green
        let bR = bufferData[i + 2] + data[i + 2]; // blue
        if (log) {
          //console.log("adding", bufferData[i + 0].toString(), "to", data[i + 0], "=", rR.toString())
          //console.log("adding", bufferData[i + 1].toString(), "to", data[i + 1], "=", gR.toString())
          //console.log("adding", bufferData[i + 2].toString(), "to", data[i + 2], "=", bR.toString())
        }
        bufferData[i + 0] = rR;
        bufferData[i + 1] = gR;
        bufferData[i + 2] = bR;
      }
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < bufferData.length; i += 4) {
      let diffThresh = 35;
      let r = bufferData[i + 0];
      let g = bufferData[i + 1];
      let b = bufferData[i + 2];
      //if (i % 3500000 === 0 && lastFrames.length == 3) {
        //console.log("----")
        //console.log("combined colors", r, g, b)
      //}
      let rA = r / lastFrames.length; // red
      let gA = g / lastFrames.length; // green
      let bA = b / lastFrames.length; // blue
      let rO = current[i + 0];
      let gO = current[i + 1];
      let bO = current[i + 2];
      let rDiff = Math.abs(rA - rO);
      let gDiff = Math.abs(gA - gO);
      let bDiff = Math.abs(bA - bO);

      if (rDiff < diffThresh && gDiff < diffThresh && bDiff < diffThresh) {
        // I thought this condition is where the pixels similar to previous frames should be added,
        // but for some reason rendering them on the opposite condition worked better
      } else {
        if (i % 40000 === 0) {
          console.log("----")
          console.log("lastFrames", lastFrames) // (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
          console.log("combined colors (", lastFrames.length, ")", r, g, b) // 155 136 120 (this should be roughly double the current value)
          console.log("averaged colors", rA, gA, bA) // 77.5 68 60 (this is always roughly half of every current colors channel)
          console.log("current colors", rO, bO, gO) // 155 120 136
          console.log("color differences", rDiff, gDiff, bDiff) // (these are wrong every time because the averaged color values are wrong)
        }
        //imageData.data[i + 0] = (r + rO * 4) / 5;
        //imageData.data[i + 1] = (g + gO * 4) / 5;
        //imageData.data[i + 2] = (b + bO * 4) / 5;

        // using 0 for debugging to see more clearly which pixels are being affected
        // realistically instead of using an absolute value to decide which pixels are
        // averaged, an average value will be added in dynamically based on how different
        // the pixel is from the same pixel in previous frames
        imageData.data[i + 0] = 0;
        imageData.data[i + 1] = 0;
        imageData.data[i + 2] = 0;
      }
    }
    c2.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  };

  const draw = (v, c, w, h, c2) => {
    if (v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);
    edit(c, w, h, c2)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      draw(v, c, w, h, c2);
    });
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var v = document.getElementById('v');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('c2');
    var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    v.addEventListener('play', function() {
      var cw = v.videoWidth;
      var ch = v.videoHeight;
      console.log("cw", cw, "ch", ch)
      canvas.width = cw;
      canvas.height = ch;
      canvas2.width = cw;
      canvas2.height = ch;
      draw(this, context, cw, ch, context2);
      //invert(context, cw, ch);
    }, false);
  }, false);
</script>
```

Logs snippet:

```
lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 240 224 224
index.html:100 averaged colors 120 112 112
index.html:101 current colors 240 224 224
index.html:102 color differences 120 112 112
index.html:97 ----
index.html:98 lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 134 107 95
index.html:100 averaged colors 67 53.5 47.5
index.html:101 current colors 134 95 107
index.html:102 color differences 67 53.5 47.5
index.html:97 ----
index.html:98 lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 246 240 241
index.html:100 averaged colors 123 120 120.5
index.html:101 current colors 246 241 240
index.html:102 color differences 123 120 120.5
index.html:97 ----
index.html:98 lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 147 118 107
index.html:100 averaged colors 73.5 59 53.5
index.html:101 current colors 147 107 118
index.html:102 color differences 73.5 59 53.5
index.html:97 ----
index.html:98 lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 245 240 243
index.html:100 averaged colors 122.5 120 121.5
index.html:101 current colors 245 243 240
index.html:102 color differences 122.5 120 121.5
index.html:97 ----
index.html:98 lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 99 56 57
index.html:100 averaged colors 49.5 28 28.5
index.html:101 current colors 99 57 56
index.html:102 color differences 49.5 28 28.5
index.html:97 ----
index.html:98 lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 245 240 243
index.html:100 averaged colors 122.5 120 121.5
index.html:101 current colors 245 243 240
index.html:102 color differences 122.5 120 121.5
index.html:97 ----
index.html:98 lastFrames (2) [ImageData, ImageData]
index.html:99 combined colors ( 2 ) 112 63 57
index.html:100 averaged colors 56 31.5 28.5
index.html:101 current colors 112 57 63
index.html:102 color differences 56 31.5 28.5
```